# Theme check: Missing a text-domain

Tags: theme-development, textdomain

I'm using following code to display the number of comments:

```
printf(_n('1 comment', '%1$s comments', get_comments_number()), number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ), 'text-domain' );
```

Is there something wrong with it?

The theme check plugin is giving the warning :

```
WARNING: Found a translation function that is missing a text-domain. Function _n, with the arguments '1 comment','%1$s comments'
```

I do not understand what it is suggesting, neither it tells in which file is the error, so I am assuming its the above code.

How I can fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Let us look at the relevant line. I am reformatting it to easier understand what is going on:

```
printf(
    _n('1 comment', '%1$s comments', get_comments_number() ),
    number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ),
    'text-domain'
);
```

So what you are doing is calling `printf` with three parameters, each one now being on a separate line now as I formatted it.

But this doesn't really make sense, especially the third parameter `text-domain` doesn't make any sense there.

What you probably want is using [`_n`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_n) to translate using a number that you put through [`number_format_i18n`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/number_format_i18n).

So I guess this is what you're looking for actually:

```
printf(
    _n( '1 comment',
        '%1$s comments',
        number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ),
        'text-domain'
      )
);
```